# How do I sort the list by running thorough every element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, user-defined-functions, enumerate

[image: Expected algorithm]
Based on the image, my code is supposed to run 'k' 12 times even though the list is already sorted at the 7th step. However, my code only ran it 6 times to achieve the sorted list. How can i make it run 12 times according to the image?

Also, I have to count the number of steps required to sort 'k', so I used enumerate but the output were 0 0 0 1 1 2. I need it to give me the output 12 instead. Am i doing something wrong?

```
    def sorting_function(k):
        for index, i in enumerate(range(len(k))):
            for num in range(len(k) - 1):
                if k[num] > k[num+1]:
                    k[num], k[num+1] = k[num+1], k[num]
                    print(index)

    k = [4, 3, 2, 1]
    sorting_function(k)
    print(k)
```

Comment: Which sorting algorithm is this? Bubble sort?

Comment: You seem to have posted the last paragraph of a larger explanation about what you are supposed to be doing.

Comment: @jarmod yes i used bubble sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line `print(index)` is indented meaning it only prints if the values are to be swapped.

The loop iterates 12 times but doesn't need to swap values on every loop.

I believe it should work like this.

```
def sorting_function(k):
    for index, i in enumerate(range(len(k))):
        for num in range(len(k) - 1):
            if k[num] > k[num+1]:
                k[num], k[num+1] = k[num+1], k[num]
            print(index)

k = [4, 3, 2, 1]
sorting_function(k)
print(k)
```

If you want to have an output of "12", create a counter variable and increment it each loop, then print it at the end after `print(k)`.

Edit:

Instead of using enumerate, you can use a counter to keep track of the total amount of times that the inner loop runs:

```
def sorting_function(k):
  counter = 0
  for i in range(len(k)):
      for num in range(len(k) - 1):
          if k[num] > k[num+1]:
              k[num], k[num+1] = k[num+1], k[num]
          counter=counter+1
          print(counter)

k = [4, 3, 2, 1]
sorting_function(k)
print(k)
```

Comment: so should i not use enumerate then?

Comment: Enumerate is currently only counting how many times the outer loop runs, you need to count the inner loop.  The issue with enumerate is it does not keep track of the total amount of times the inner loop is run as it resets the counter every time the outer loop runs.

Comment: ohhh i see! thanks a lot! you're a great help :)

Comment: I added an example with the counter in my answer.  Hope this helps :)